# WPF & resolution independent

Tags: wpf

if i put everything in viewbox container then my wpf apps will be resolution independent or do i need to do anything else. please help with concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Scale elements accordingly to the available screen or medium size**
If your desire is, to allways fill some room of the screen or output device, independently of the metrics, using the viewbox is a good choice. If you have a big monitor, you will have a big element, if you have a small paper, you will have a small print out of the same element.
With the [Stretch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.stretch.aspx)-property of an image you have a similar possibility only for pictures.

**Make elements on every device equaly sized**
WPF is designed "resolution independent". The goal of this resolution indepency is, that if you design an element to be 15 inches, then it will be on every output medium this 15 inches, independently of the resolution of your output device. Calculaction and specification of dimensions is done in "device independent pixels" [(DIP)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2009/12/11/wpf-text-measurement-units.aspx) which you can convert to centimeters or inches without having specific knowledge about the output devices resolution.

96DIP == 1inch == 2.54cm;
1 inch == 96DPI;
1 cm == 37.8DIP;

If want to use this resolution indepency, you can set fixed values (in DIPs) to your elements. On a large monitor then your element then maybe only uses a small part (e.G. 15inches), and on a small monitor it fills the whole screen (also 15inches).

Answer (score 3):

WPF is resolution independent without any extra tricks at all. If you host legacy controls (non-WPF controls) then this may break for them, but WPF itself is resolutions independent and vector based.

Answer (score 3):

Viewbox has nothing to do with resolution independence.

Resolution independence means, controls you specify can be drawn on different resolutions while keeping scale. So you can use display that has 10x bigger density of points, but controls will still look same to you.

And like it was said, WPF itself was designed with this in mind, you dont have to do anything.